# sql limit fail to display first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a SQL-query which looks like:

```
    `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5;`
```

in fact I use mysql's free employees database and the query is:

```
    `SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 5;`
```

now I have a PHP function which outputs the selected data into a HTML table which looks like this:

```
function outputTable($query, $link){
     //Verbindung zur Datenbank inkludieren
    require_once('./config.php');
    //auffangen der Rückgabe
    $erg = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    //bestimmt Anzahl der Spalten (aocol = Amount Of COLumns)
    //counts the amount of columns
    $aocol = count(mysqli_fetch_array($erg, MYSQLI_NUM));
    //table head
    $head = "";
    for($x = 0; $x < $aocol; $x++) {
        //legt alle Informationen des Feldes $x in $finfo, darunter auch den Namen der Spalte.
        //puts all information of the field $x in $finfo, also the name of the column
        $finfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($erg, $x);
        //Schreibt die Kopfzeile der Tabelle
        //writes the table's head
        $head .= "<th>".$finfo->name."</th>";
    }
    //only if style.css included-->irrelevant
    echo '<div class="table"><table id="table">';
    //output of table's head
    echo "<th>$head</th>";
    //output of table's body --> here must be the bug, I think
    while($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($erg, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        //new tablerow
        echo "<tr>";
        //filling the row
        foreach($zeile as $feld) {
            //format for numbers
            $ra = preg_match('/^\d+$/',$feld) ? ' align="right"' : '';
            //displaying table data
            echo "<td$ra>".$feld."</td>";
        }
    }
    //closing table and layout
    echo '</table></div>';
}
```

My problem is that rows 2-5 are written, but the first row is missing...
if you execute the query, you should get something like this:

```
| emp_no | 
|  10001 | 
|  10002 | 
|  10003 | 
|  10004 | 
|  10005 |
```

I in fact get only the emp_nos 10002-10005.

Comment: I get: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by emp_no' at line 1`

Comment: My bad, wrong way around.. `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY emp_no LIMIT 5;`

Comment: because it is: 'Select * from table order by emp_no limit 5;' but it is still the same result so first row missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call...

```
$aocol = count(mysqli_fetch_array($erg, MYSQLI_NUM));
```

this is in fact reading the first line and therefore it is no longer available for the following loop.

I would suggest restructuring your code so that the head is built up inside the main read loop, but only when `$head` is empty...

```
//table head
$head = "";

//only if style.css included-->irrelevant
echo '<div class="table"><table id="table">';
//output of table's body --> here must be the bug, I think
while($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($erg, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    if ( empty ($head) )    {
        //counts the amount of columns
        $aocol = count($zeile);
        for($x = 0; $x < $aocol; $x++) {
            //legt alle Informationen des Feldes $x in $finfo, darunter auch den Namen der Spalte.
            //puts all information of the field $x in $finfo, also the name of the column
            $finfo = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($erg, $x);
            //Schreibt die Kopfzeile der Tabelle
            //writes the table's head
            $head .= "<th>".$finfo->name."</th>";
        }
        //output of table's head
        echo "<th>$head</th>";
    }
    //new tablerow
    echo "<tr>";
    //filling the row
    foreach($zeile as $feld) {
        //format for numbers
        $ra = preg_match('/^\d+$/',$feld) ? ' align="right"' : '';
        //displaying table data
        echo "<td$ra>".$feld."</td>";
    }
}
```

Also, if you changed `MYSQLI_NUM` to `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, then you can just use the key names as the column name and remove the extra API calls...

```
while($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array($erg, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ( empty ($head) )    {
        foreach ( $zeile as $name => $value )   {
            $head .= "<th>".$name."</th>";
        }
        //output of table's head
        echo "<th>$head</th>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a query like this to get all the results:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY  `id` LIMIT 0, 5";
```

This will only give you the first 5 results to make more you can then:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY  `id` LIMIT 5, 100";
```

Or this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: In fact I think that there is somehow a bug in the whole loop, but I can't find it

Comment: Give a try on my last query example and tell me what you got in return

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array` already fetches the results as an array.

I suspect it's moving the mysql cursor after the fetch, which is why you're missing the first row.

A much simpler solution might be something like this:

```
function outputTable($query, $link) {
    require_once('./config.php');
    $erg = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($erg, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $aocol = count($result);
    $head = "";
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $head .= '<th>' . $row['name'] . '</th>';
    }
    echo '<div class="table"><table id="table">';
    echo "<th>$head</th>";
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $field) {
            $ra = preg_match('/^\d+$/',$field) ? ' align="right"' : '';
            echo "<td$ra>".$field."</td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</table></div>';
}
```